# Удаление файлов по расписанию

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, необходимо написать класс, который по расписанию бы удалял файлы и делал проверку раз в день на истекшие сроки.
Думаю, что можно это реализовать через Spring Scheduled , но еще не работал с этим.
Буду признателен любой наметки, даже простейшего метода - экземпляра, что бы по нему примерно уже сделать.

Answer (score 0):

возможно, ваша программа должна делать что-то следующее: один из потоков будет спать, пока его не разбудят, а проснувшись удалит файл/файлы (например через консольную команду). другой-же поток будет в цикле просыпаться раз в сутки и обновлять таймер/счетчик (записывать в него системное время, а потом ждать 24 часа). если подошло время - второй поток будит первый, а потом засыпает. первый поток удаляет файлы, и так-же уходит в сон.

Comment: Очень интересное предложение, спасибо)